# Flag comment option unavailability

Tags: support, bug, flagging

The option to flag a comment is unavailable in the mobile version of Chrome.(atleast for me)
But it is available in the desktop view/version.

This creates the following issues:

1. New users who were introduced through a mobile version interface will be unaware of the option to flag a comment.
2. General inconvenience of reloading and changing views from mobile to desktop version for someone who prefers mobile(like me).

I personally experienced this when I was a relatively new user and wanted to flag a comment. It isn't really a major issue but maybe I should report it here I thought?

Maybe it's just a problem with my device/software? This is the best way to find out.

Following are screenshots that might help understand/comprehend.

Desktop view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UoBu.png

Mobile view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5RBb.png

Comment: I also have similar issues, when I login from a mobile device. There's just a single option to upvote, no flagging option available. It seems like it is a universal problem rather than problem with a specific device.

Comment: Moreover the tips which show up while writing an answer via a desktop interface don't show up in case of a mobile interface and thus prevents new users from knowing how to properly use the available tools to ask/answer a good and well formatted question. I doubt most of the new posts which don't use proper typesetting and formatting might be a direct impact of this. Even while writing comments the "help" button is nowhere to be seen!

Comment: Stackexchange was not meant to be used on mobile. This is not something that can be done by moderators and it has been taken up on mother meta and considered [status-completed] by SE staff. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213709/allow-flagging-comments-on-mobile-site. Also See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100706/how-do-i-delete-or-flag-comments-using-the-mobile-website.

Comment: Also flagging a comment shouldn't be such a common place thing where in you would need to switch from one mode to another, If that is the case, then are you flagging properly?

Comment: @Safdar Yes I agree flagging isn't common. I don't even use it much. But I just thought of it from the community perspective - a new contributor who likes to/has time to contribute by flagging voids. I sometimes have the time, patience and inspiration to go through questions and edit/flag them to help contribute a little to the community. And when you're on a 'flag unnecessary comments spree' it gets a little inconvenient because the desktop view isn't that manageable on a mobile device. That's why I mentioned it's not a major issue. Also wanted to just have a discussion about its prevalence.